# Are Apache and MySQL servers needed in addition to MAMP?

Tags: installation, mamp

This might be a silly question, but I'm new to web-dev, so here it is:

I recently installed MAMP on my windows system [yes, MAMP works on windows too] and it shows Apache and MySQL server to be active, but neither I have installed any of these servers, nor I can find them in "Services" of my system.
So I wanted to ask whether I'll need to  explicitly install both of these servers or not.

Also, If there's no need of explicit installation, how does MAMP work ? like, giving access to both these servers without actually installing them ? [A brief explanation would be enough]

T.I.A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They come with MAMP.  You can access phpMyAdmin under the Tools menu in the page that automatically opens up when you start MAMP, for me it is http://localhost/MAMP/?language=English